# PostgreSQL delimiter to separate multiple queries in queries file

Tags: sql, postgresql, delimiter

I have file with multiple queries. How can I separate them using DELIMITER?
I tried it like in mysql but it didn't copile:

```
DELIMITER %

CREATE SEQUENCE logins_seq
  INCREMENT BY 1
  START WITH 1
%

CREATE TABLE logins (
  login_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
)
%
```

without delimiter it throws error:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE logins_seq
  INCREMENT BY 1
  START WITH 1


CREATE TABLE logins (
  login_name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: you are already terminating statements with `;`. why do you need another delimiter?

Comment: You don't need that. Postgres uses the standard delimiter `;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default delimiter that separates statements is by `;`, so your queries should already be separated in your file and there is no need to define a delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use delimiter `%` in postgresql? You already have delimiter `;`